# The wifi connection of my computer has disappeared

Tags: wireless

This morning my WiFi connection in my Kubuntu worked fine. Now, I start my computer and then It doesn't works! Why? I didn't update nothing.

Comment: In order to get some help, you should edit your post and be more specific. What version of Kubuntu are you using ? Define 'doesn't work' ...

Comment: Kubuntu 16,04 LTS. I think that the problem is hardware, because the bluetooth is disappeated too. I think is the hard controller.